# scope count multiple string names?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to do `<%= @user.challenges.habit_badge.count %>`, but I don't know how I can get the scope to work to include multiple `name` strings I want to include in the `habit_badge` count.

```
  scope :habit_badge, -> do
    where(name: ('Read 20 Min', 'Run a Mile', 'Meditate 10 Min', etc....))
  end

  def habit_badge
    if name == "Read 20 Min"
      ActionController::Base.helpers.image_tag("read.png", class: "gold-star")
    elsif name == "Exercise 20 Min"
      ActionController::Base.helpers.image_tag("exercise.png", class: "gold-star")
    elsif name == "Meditate 10 Min"
      ActionController::Base.helpers.image_tag("meditate.png", class: "gold-star")
    elsif name == "Stretch 5 Min"
      ActionController::Base.helpers.image_tag("stretch.png", class: "gold-star")
    elsif name == "Write 500 Words"
      ActionController::Base.helpers.image_tag("write.png", class: "gold-star")
    elsif name == "Walk 5,000 Steps"
      ActionController::Base.helpers.image_tag("walk.png", class: "gold-star")
    elsif name == "Eat Fruit & Veg"
      ActionController::Base.helpers.image_tag("fruit-and-vegetable.png", class: "gold-star")
    elsif name == "Plan Day"
      ActionController::Base.helpers.image_tag("plan.png", class: "gold-star")
    elsif name == "After Waking, Guzzle Water"
      ActionController::Base.helpers.image_tag("water.png", class: "gold-star")
    elsif name == "Track Consumption"
      ActionController::Base.helpers.image_tag("track-food.png", class: "gold-star")
    elsif name == "Random Act of Kindness"
      ActionController::Base.helpers.image_tag("random-kindness.png", class: "gold-star")
    elsif name == "Write 3 Gratitudes"
      ActionController::Base.helpers.image_tag("gratitude.png", class: "gold-star")
    elsif name == "Juice Fast"
      ActionController::Base.helpers.image_tag("juice.png", class: "gold-star")
    elsif name == "Not Smoke"
      ActionController::Base.helpers.image_tag("not-smoke.png", class: "gold-star")
    elsif name == "Not Drink Alcohol"
      ActionController::Base.helpers.image_tag("not-drink.png", class: "gold-star")
    else
      ActionController::Base.helpers.image_tag("gold-star-maze.png", class: "gold-star")
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass an array of names to scope:

```
scope :habit_badge, -> {
  where(name: ['Read 20 Min', 'Run a Mile', 'Meditate 10 Min'])
}
```

It will be treated as:

```
SELECT "resources".* FROM "resources" WHERE "resources"."name" IN ('Read 20 Min', 'Run a Mile', 'Meditate 10 Min')
```

Comment: Ah perfect! I was so close lol. I'll check mark when I'm allowed, but in the meantime you think I'm doing this the most efficient way or is there a better way idk best practices for string conditionals?

Comment: @AnthonyGalli.com yea, you were almost there! As to scope - indeed, it is the correct and efficient and conventional way. As to `habit_badge` method - it definitely **do not** belongs to model. It should be moved to some helper or presenter, but for sure not model.